# How to achieve a LinearLayout with fixed percentage width like this?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I am trying to achieve the following layout for a CardView:

[image: What I want]

**Each one is a different CardView**

I would like every CardView to have the same "columns" width. I know little about the **weight** property and I guess I am using it wrong. As far as I have read, the weight property will tell the "priority" of the elements to ocuppy space. I have tried this solution:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:id="@+id/main_flat_item"
 >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.example.myapp.VerticalTextView
        android:text="CODE"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:background="@color/td_main_blue"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/grayE" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Taxa compra"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@color/grayB"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Taxa Compra"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/td_green"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Taxa venda"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textColor="@color/grayB"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Taxa Venda"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textColor="@color/td_red" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/grayE" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:button="@drawable/star_checkbox" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

But altough I have set some weight properties I end up with things like:

[image: Result example :(]

So:

- Do I have to set weight to all of my childrens inside de LinearLayout? What do I do with the "fixed" width elements (like the left bar and the line separator).

  - Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the new percentage support library: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#percent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layout weights work as a ratio of all the elements in a block. So for example if you had three `textviews` in a `linearlayout` with weights of 1, 2 and 1, the second `textview` would be twice as large as the other two, or take up 50% of the available space. The total sum doesn't matter, just the ratio between numbers, so in the above example I could use 0.5:1:0.5 or 100:200:100, and it would come out the same.

So in your code, in the outermost `LinearLayout` you only have three items with weights: The first `TextView` and the two nested `LinearLayout`s, with 0.5, 0.3 and 0.2 respectively. So Android will provide space to all of your fixed-width elements, and then of the remaining space, the `TextView` will get 5/10 and the `LinearLayout`s will get 3/10 and 2/10.

Also, weight works best if the item with the weight has a size of 0dp in the direction being stretched. If you're using Android Studio it should have given you a warning about this.

Comment: Thanks TBridges. The Android Studio didn't warn me about the 0dp thing. I read it was only about performance but changing it to 0dp actually made it work. Thanks a lot! :D